# How to get a certain enum instance when we are given only 1 value of its parameters?

Tags: java, enums

Please find my enum class below:

```
public enum CountryCode //implements IEnum
{
AD("Andorra", "AND", "Europe", "South West Europe"),
AE("United Arab Emirates", "ARE", "Asia", "South West Asia"),
AF("Afghanistan", "AFG", "Asia", "South Asia"),
// and so one till Z

// attributes defined
private final String label;
private final String isoCode3;
private final String continent;
private final String region;

// countructor defined
private CountryCode(String label, String isoCode3, String continent, String region)
{
    this.label = label;
    this.isoCode3 = isoCode3;
    this.continent = continent;
    this.region = region;

}   // END CountryCode

} // END enum CountryCode
```

NOW if I am given just the country name i.e. label, so how would I get its corresponding enum instance? So if given "Andorra", I want `AD`.

Comment: So if given Andorra, you want AD?

Comment: @GI Joe , Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would cache the relations within a Map where the keys are the labels and the values the corresponding CountryCode insances. This way, you iterate over the CountryCode instances only once instead of each time the `getByLabel()` method gets called.

```java
public enum CountryCode {

    AD("Andorra", "AND", "Europe", "South West Europe"),
    AE("United Arab Emirates", "ARE", "Asia", "South West Asia"),
    AF("Afghanistan", "AFG", "Asia", "South Asia");

    private static final Map<String, CountryCode> BY_LABEL;
    static {
        Map<String, CountryCode> byLabel = new HashMap<String, CountryCode>();
        for (CountryCode countryCode : values()) {
            byLabel.put(countryCode.label, countryCode);
        }
        BY_LABEL = Collections.unmodifiableMap(byLabel);
    }

    private final String label;
    private final String isoCode3;
    private final String continent;
    private final String region;

    private CountryCode(String label, String isoCode3, String continent, String region) {
        this.label = label;
        this.isoCode3 = isoCode3;
        this.continent = continent;
        this.region = region;
    }

    public static CountryCode getByLabel(String label) {
        return BY_LABEL.get(label);
    }

}
```

Then, simply call:

```java
CountryCode countryCode = CountryCode.getByLabel("Andorra");
```

Comment: What if you initialized the `enum` as `AD("AND", "Europe", "South West Europe");` etc and had an `EnumMap` that contained all the `enum's` with their corresponding country name?

Comment: Thanks, Now what if I have a value such as "AD" in string form, how to get it convert or parse to CountryCode type?

Comment: @GIJoe I don't really get what you mean, but you can have as many inner constant maps as you need (e.g. `BY_ISO_CODE_3`, `BY_CONTINENT`). Thus, you would simply need to create corresponding `getByIsoCode3()` and `getByContinent()` static methods.

Comment: @Amir Simply use the native `CountryCode.valueOf("AD")` method.

Comment: Yea got it, it was simple!

Answer (score 1):

First let's see the simple but ineffective solution:

```
public static CountryCode  getCountryCodeByLabel(String label)
    for(CountryCode  c : CountryCode.values()) {
        if(label.equals(c.label())) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To improve this solution you can create `Map` inside your enum and call its `put()` into constructor. In this case `getCountryCodeByLabel(String label)` will look like:

```
public static CountryCode  getCountryCodeByLabel(String label)
    return labels.get(label);
}
```

Obviously you can create several such maps: each one can use different field as a key.

EDIT:

Take a look on my article http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-customized-valueof where I explain this issue in details.

You can also read my blog: http://alexradzin.blogspot.co.il/2010/10/customized-valueof.html

Comment: So a `Map` consisting of the `Enum` and it's country name (which the `Enum` already has the country name)? Seems like duplication for the opportunity to have an efficient lookup. It would be nice if you didn't have to duplicate anything and use what's already in the Enum

Comment: I have already tried by the first approach that you mentioned, but it throws an exception! and for the second code, is it syntactically correct?

Comment: I was thinking EnumMap but I don't know how to implement it for this case.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you provide it wouldn't be possible. You would need to have a method to get the `label` from the enum's values. Or a method in the enum that returns the code from a `label`. I show the first way below.

```
public enum CountryCode {
  AD("Andorra", "AND", "Europe", "South West Europe"),
  AE("United Arab Emirates", "ARE", "Asia", "South West Asia"),
  AF("Afghanistan", "AFG", "Asia", "South Asia");
  // and so one till Z

  // attributes defined
  private final String label;
  private final String isoCode3;
  private final String continent;
  private final String region;

  // countructor defined
  private CountryCode(String label, String isoCode3, String continent, String region) {
    this.label = label;
    this.isoCode3 = isoCode3;
    this.continent = continent;
    this.region = region;
  } // END CountryCode
  // ADDED THIS 
  public String getLabel() {
    return this.label;
  }// END ADDED THIS :)
} // END enum CountryCode
```

And after you loop the values and find the one matching the label

```
for (CountryCode cc : CountryCode.values()) {
  cc.getLabel().equals(yourCode) {
    // cc is the correct CountryCode
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried already in this way, its not working and throwing exception = list!java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You added a method to get the label and get the exception when??